# Order of elements in quotient Q/Z

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I have a question asking me to compute the order of:

$\frac 8 9 +\Bbb Z$, $\frac {14} 5 +\Bbb Z$, and $\frac {48} {28} +\Bbb Z$

in the quotient $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.

I think the answer is order 9, 5, and 7 respectively but would like some clarification as to why that is the case.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to group theory.

Comment: For example, what is that number $n$ such that $n \cdot \frac 89$ is an integer? It's $9$: this is the order of a fraction inside $\Bbb{Q/Z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an element $r+\mathbb{Z}$ ($r\in\mathbb{Q}$) in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ the order of such an element would be the smallest natural number $a$ such that $ar\in \mathbb{Z}$. This is because in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ if $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $r+\mathbb{Z}=0+\mathbb{Z}$ which is the identity element of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.
To find this all you need do is write $r$ in lowest terms i.e. $r=\frac{p}{q}$ for coprime integers $p,q$ with $q>0$ then this $q$ is the value of $a$ you are looking for so in your example we have:

1. $r=\frac{8}{9}$ which is already in lowest terms so the order of $\frac{8}{9}+\mathbb{Z}$ is 9.
2. $r=\frac{14}{5}$, again already in lowest terms so the order of $\frac{14}{5}+\mathbb{Z}$ is 5.
3. $r=\frac{48}{28}$ which in lowest terms is $\frac{12}{7}$ and so the order of $r=\frac{48}{28}+\mathbb{Z}$ is 7.

I hope this clears things up for you.

Answer (score 5):

The order of a coset $a+\mathbb Z$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $na\in \mathbb Z$. This is equivalent to saying that
$$n(a+\mathbb Z)=0+\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z$$
and $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that this holds.

Comment: Perfect! This explained what I was confused about.